# Hex to color name

Tags: hex, rgb

I want to tag color names based on hex or rgb values. I found this amazing site ( http://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue/ ) but the thing is there are so many color names and main color hues are insufficient. I would love to have a solution to name RGB or HEX for like 40-50 well known colors.

Any idea will help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This [one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json) will be useful, you will have to parse this json to use it in your project.

Comment: thank you! My question is, what if my color code falls in between of two tagged colors, I guess it won't tag right?

Comment: you could then tag in similar color

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a command-line tool that does exactly that: [Cict](https://github.com/kallaballa/Cict)

Example:

```
$ ./cict 000081
1   #000080 navyblue
```

As you can see, you simple pass a 24-bit hex-value to cict and it reports the distance to the color found (1 in this case), the value of the actual color (#000080) and the name (navyblue).